# Defining a Sum of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Given that a (real) random variable $X$ is a measurable map from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, how do we define a sum of random variables $X+Y$?

To elaborate, I've seen results which use random vectors and compositions of measurable maps to argue that $X+Y$ is a random variable, but it seems that the proof technique necessarily requires that $X,Y$ be defined on the same probability space. Intuitively this makes sense, since a sum of functions defined on different domains seems nonsensical.

But then if we're given say, a Bernoulli random variable $X$ and a Gaussian Random variable $Y$, can we guarantee that there is a common probability space and variables $X,Y$ defined on that space such that $P_{X}(:=P\circ X^{-1})$ and $P_{Y}$ are Bernoulli and Gaussian distributions, respectively?

Or, alternatively, can we use the convolution of probability measures to define $X+Y$ as any random variable with distribution $P_{X+Y}=P_{X}*P_{Y}$, since we seem to really only care about distributions, anyway?

Comment: $(X+Y)(\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$ for $\omega\in\Omega$, how else?

Comment: In that case, can we always find a common probability space for two types of random variable (like Bernoulli and Binomial) so that the sum is well defined?

Comment: Yes we can. If $X$ is some random variable defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and $Y$ on $(\Psi,\mathcal G,Q)$, define $Z$ on $\Omega\times\Psi$ by $Z(\omega,\psi)=X(\omega)+Y(\psi)$, then $Z$ has the desired distribution $P_X\ast Q_Y$ on $(\Omega\times\Psi,\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal G,P\otimes Q)$. Additionally, $\bar X:(\omega,\psi)\mapsto X(\omega)$ and $\bar Y:(\omega,\psi)\mapsto Y(\psi)$ are independent, $\bar X$ has distribution $P_X$ and $\bar Y$ has distribution $Q_Y$.

Comment: @428 are you also asking if we need to define them on the same probability space?